# jQuery: Div header not clearing on .Hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div tag for a jQuery modal window, setup as follows:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Please select a facility"  style="clear:both;width:400px;display:none;text-align:left;height:200px;overflow-y:scroll"></div>
```

I then open the popup with the following:

```
$("#dialog").html(result);

$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    resizable: true,
    modal: true,
    width: 'auto'
});
```

I then try to hide the div tag using $("#dialog").hide(); but I'm having an issue.  The contents of my div tag does hide successfully, however my header remains.  You can see an example of this in the below image.  In the first image, my "Please select a facility" modal window pops up successfully.  In image #2, I then switch to a 2nd popup and hide the original popup using "$("#dialog").hide().  Which seems to work, but as you can see in image #3, my "Please select a facility" modal window header, remains open.  Any idea why this header isn't hiding?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more code, maybe a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog("close");
```